Firestock database creation inquiry
I have a signup page for my app , it includes name , email , password , age , profile picture and country informations . and on the login page there is email and password fields. My question is this : how to approach the database creation , should i use firebase authentication ? and how to get a coherent database where everything is connected properly . (i'm new to firebase and i got a website project that's due on friday).
